# How to fix numpy string error

Tags: python, numpy

I am using numpy to create an array out of a `.csv` file. This file's top row is made up of text, so I copied this command from the article I was using to leave it out when using float(I have left in the whole code for context. The command is the `[1:]` in the last line)

```
import numpy as np
import csv
with open("atest.csv", 'r') as f:
    wines = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=";"))
    print(wines[:3])
wines_array = np.array(wines[1:], dtype=np.float)
```

However, I still get this error message:

```
    wines_array = np.array(wines[1:], dtype=np.float)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'fixed acidity'
```

This indicates that it has not left out the top row. Does anyone have any help?

**EDIT**

This is my `.csv` file:

```
"fixed acidity";"volatile acidity";"citric acid";"residual sugar";"chlorides";"free sulfur dioxide";"total sulfur dioxide";"density";"pH";"sulphates";"alcohol";"quality"
7.4;0.7;0;1.9;0.076;11;34;0.9978;3.51;0.56;9.4;5
7.8;0.88;0;2.6;0.098;25;67;0.9968;3.2;0.68;9.8;5
```

The first line is all one row in my file.

Comment: show your .csv.

Comment: ^ That, and you really should be using something like `np.loadtxt` or `genfromtxt` or `pandas`.

Comment: Ok, I'm about to post the first three lines of my csv.

Comment: fixed acidity;"volatile acidity";"citric acid";"residual sugar";"chlorides";"free sulfur dioxide";"total sulfur dioxide";"density";"pH";"sulphates";"alcohol";"quality"
7.4;0.7;0;1.9;0.076;11;34;0.9978;3.51;0.56;9.4;5
7.8;0.88;0;2.6;0.098;25;67;0.9968;3.2;0.68;9.8;5

Comment: I have corrected the quote mark error around "Fixed acidity" but it still does not work. @eyllanesc

Comment: edit your question and add it there.

Comment: One moment @eyllanesc

Comment: Question edited @eyllanesc

Comment: I have tested your code and it runs correctly.

Comment: Strange, what version are you @eyllanesc?

Comment: python 3.6.4 - python 2.7.14 - numpy 1.13.3

Comment: Try this: `import pandas; v = pd.read_csv('file.csv', error_bad_lines=False).values`

Comment: Above code works for mine as well. Can you check result of print(wines[1:]). This should print your list without the headers. If it printed then that means that either your csv was not parsed correctly.

Comment: I'll try in a moment@cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, I just need to download pandas

Comment: Yep, the headers are printed.@user8505495

Comment: Can you show the result of that command? I was thinking there might be something wrong with the csv or how we parse the csv,

Comment: I put the error message up in the question@user8505495

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, the code works without any errors.

Comment: Good! You’re welcome. Feel free to write it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that python wasn't parsing the file properly, so I switched libraries to `pandas` and slightly modified and used the code suggested by the user COLDSPEED in the comments. The error appears to be individual to me.

Here is the line of code I used:
`import pandas as pd; v = pd.read_csv('atestred.csv', error_bad_lines=False).values`

Comment: Make sure to add the code you used, so as to help other users with the same problem.

Comment: One sec @COLDSPEED